# Constructing a tooltip values of bar from json file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, tooltip, bar-chart

I'm currently struggling making the tooltip work. Here's how the page looks like [See Photo1 below], and I'm trying to assign to every bar it's y value. The y value's are stored in `resumeperday.json` [See below] which has 'time' and 'y' attributes for everyday. time attribute is the date, and y is how many orders were during that day. that `resumeperday.json` file is stored as `dataset` variable in `index.html` file. I'm trying to parse its y value which is sum of all the three different orders (every date has 3 different values) and show it on the bar when mouse is hovering it. When I'm using this line of code

```
  .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>Number of orders:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
                        return d3.max(d, function(d) {
                            return d.y0 + d.y;
                        });
                    }) + "</span>";
        })
```

**Problem:** It shows only `123` for every bar (which is the maximum value of orders), I'm trying to build a function that will return the value according to the specific bar that was hovered.

**Here's the index.html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pizza orders</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
        .axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.dot {
  stroke: #000;
}


.legend {
                padding: 5px;
                font: 10px sans-serif;
                background: yellow;
                box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #888;
            }
.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}-align: center;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                         Pizza orders per hour <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a class="m" value="2018-07-15" href="#">2018-07-15</a></li>
                    <li><a class="m" value="2018-07-16" href="#">2018-07-16</a></li>
                    <li><a class="m" value="2018-07-17" href="#">2018-07-17</a></li>
                    <li><a class="m" value="2018-07-18" href="#">2018-07-18</a></li>
                    <li><a class="m" value="2018-07-19" href="#">2018-07-19</a></li>
                    <li><a class="m" value="2018-07-20" href="#">2018-07-20</a></li>
                    <li><a class="m" value="2018-07-21" href="#">2018-07-21</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        <div id="mbars">
        </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var w = 700;                        //width
        var h = 600;                        //height
        var padding = {top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40, left:25};
        var dataset;
        var tip = d3.tip()
        .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
        .offset([-10, 0])
        .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>Number of orders:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d3.min(dataset, function(d) {
                        return d3.min(d, function(d) {
                            return d.y0 + d.y;
                        });
                    }) + "</span>";
        })
        //Set up stack method
        var stack = d3.layout.stack();

        d3.json("resumeperday.json",function(json){
            dataset = json;

            //Data, stacked
            stack(dataset);

            var color_hash = {
                    0 : ["50-70₪","#0000FF"],
                    1 : ["70.00-120₪","#FF0000"],
                    2 : ["120+₪","#04B404"]

            };


            //Set up scales
            var xScale = d3.time.scale()
                .domain([new Date(dataset[0][0].time),d3.time.day.offset(new Date(dataset[0][dataset[0].length-1].time),2)])
                .rangeRound([0, w-padding.left-padding.right]);

            var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0,             
                    d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
                        return d3.max(d, function(d) {
                            return d.y0 + d.y;
                        });
                    })
                ])
                .range([h-padding.bottom-padding.top,0]);

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                           .scale(xScale)
                           .orient("bottom")
                           .ticks(d3.time.days,1);

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                           .scale(yScale)
                           .orient("left")
                           .ticks(10);



            //Easy colors accessible via a 10-step ordinal scale
            var colors = d3.scale.category10();

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("#mbars")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            svg.call(tip);


            // Add a group for each row of data
            var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class","rgroups")
                .attr("transform","translate("+ (padding.left) + "," + (h - padding.bottom) +")")
                .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                    return color_hash[dataset.indexOf(d)][1];
                })
                .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

            // Add a rect for each data value
            var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
                .data(function(d) { return d; })
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", 2)
                .style("fill-opacity",1e-6);


            rects.transition()
                 .duration(function(d,i){
                     return 500 * i;
                 })
                 .ease("linear")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return xScale(new Date(d.time));
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return -(- yScale(d.y0) - yScale(d.y) + (h - padding.top - padding.bottom)*2);
                })
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return -yScale(d.y) + (h - padding.top - padding.bottom);
                })
                .attr("width", 15)
                .style("fill-opacity",1);

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class","x axis")
                    .attr("transform","translate(40," + (h - padding.bottom) + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);


                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class","y axis")
                    .attr("transform","translate(" + padding.left + "," + padding.top + ")")
                    .call(yAxis);

                // adding legend

                var legend = svg.append("g")
                                .attr("class","legend")
                                .attr("x", w - padding.right - 65)
                                .attr("y", 25)
                                .attr("height", 100)
                                .attr("width",100);

                legend.selectAll("g").data(dataset)
                      .enter()
                      .append('g')
                      .each(function(d,i){
                        var g = d3.select(this);
                        g.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", w - padding.right - 30)
                            .attr("y", i*25 + 10)
                            .attr("width", 10)
                            .attr("height",10)
                            .style("fill",color_hash[String(i)][1]);

                        g.append("text")
                         .attr("x", w - padding.right - 15)
                         .attr("y", i*25 + 20)
                         .attr("height",30)
                         .attr("width",100)
                         .style("fill",color_hash[String(i)][1])
                         .text(color_hash[String(i)][0]);
                      });

                svg.append("text")
                .attr("transform","translate(5,20) rotate(0)")
                .attr("font-weight","bold")
                .text("Pizza Orders");

            svg.append("text")
               .attr("class","xtext")
               .attr("x",w/2 - padding.left)
               .attr("y",h - 5)
               .attr("text-anchor","middle")
               .attr("font-weight","bold")
               .text("Days");

            svg.append("text")
            .attr("class","title")
            .attr("x", (w / 2))             
            .attr("y", 20)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("font-weight","bold")         
            .style("font-size", "16px") 
            .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
            .text("Number of Pizza Orders per day");

            //On click, update with new data            
            d3.selectAll(".m")
                .on("click", function() {
                    var date = this.getAttribute("value");

                    var str;
                    if(date == "2018-07-15"){
                        str = "15.json";
                    }else if(date == "2018-07-16"){
                        str = "16.json";
                    }else if(date == "2018-07-17"){
                        str = "17.json";
                    }else if(date == "2018-07-18"){
                        str = "18.json";
                    }else if(date == "2018-07-19"){
                        str = "19.json";
                    }
                    else if(date == "2018-07-20"){
                        str = "20.json";
                    }else{
                        str = "21.json";
                    }

                    d3.json(str,function(json){

                        dataset = json;
                        stack(dataset);

                        console.log(dataset);

                        xScale.domain([new Date(0, 0, 0,dataset[0][0].time,0, 0, 0),new Date(0, 0, 0,dataset[0][dataset[0].length-1].time,0, 0, 0)])
                        .rangeRound([0, w-padding.left-padding.right]);

                        yScale.domain([0,               
                                        d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
                                            return d3.max(d, function(d) {
                                                return d.y0 + d.y;
                                            });
                                        })
                                    ])
                                    .range([h-padding.bottom-padding.top,0]);

                        xAxis.scale(xScale)
                             .ticks(d3.time.hour,1)
                             .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H"));

                        yAxis.scale(yScale)
                             .orient("left")
                             .ticks(10);

                         groups = svg.selectAll(".rgroups")
                            .data(dataset);

                            groups.enter().append("g")
                            .attr("class","rgroups")
                            .attr("transform","translate("+ padding.left + "," + (h - padding.bottom) +")")
                            .style("fill",function(d,i){
                                return color(i);
                            });


                            rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
                            .data(function(d){return d;});

                            rect.enter()
                              .append("rect")
                              .attr("x",w)
                              .attr("width",1)
                              .style("fill-opacity",1e-6);

                        rect.transition()
                            .duration(1000)
                            .ease("linear")
                            .attr("x",function(d){
                                return xScale(new Date(0, 0, 0,d.time,0, 0, 0));
                            })
                            .attr("y",function(d){
                                return -(- yScale(d.y0) - yScale(d.y) + (h - padding.top - padding.bottom)*2);
                            })
                            .attr("height",function(d){
                                return -yScale(d.y) + (h - padding.top - padding.bottom);
                            })
                            .attr("width",15)
                            .style("fill-opacity",1);

                        rect.exit()
                           .transition()
                           .duration(1000)
                           .ease("circle")
                           .attr("x",w)
                           .remove();

                        groups.exit()
                           .transition()
                           .duration(1000)
                           .ease("circle")
                           .attr("x",w)
                           .remove();


                        svg.select(".x.axis")
                           .transition()
                           .duration(1000)
                           .ease("circle")
                           .call(xAxis);

                        svg.select(".y.axis")
                           .transition()
                           .duration(1000)
                           .ease("circle")
                           .call(yAxis);

                        svg.select(".xtext")
                           .text("Hours")
                           .attr("font-weight","bold");

                        svg.select(".title")
                        .text("Number of Pizza Orders per hour on " + date)
                        .attr("font-weight","bold");
                    });         
                });


        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`resumeperday.json` file:

```
[
    [
        {
            "time": "2018-07-15",
            "y": 27
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-16",
            "y": 23
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-17",
            "y": 28
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-18",
            "y": 20
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-19",
            "y": 22
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-20",
            "y": 27
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-21",
            "y": 21
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "time": "2018-07-15",
            "y": 29
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-16",
            "y": 26
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-17",
            "y": 31
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-18",
            "y": 27
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-19",
            "y": 31
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-20",
            "y": 65
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-21",
            "y": 37
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "time": "2018-07-15",
            "y": 17
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-16",
            "y": 16
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-17",
            "y": 16
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-18",
            "y": 15
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-19",
            "y": 22
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-20",
            "y": 31
        },
        {
            "time": "2018-07-21",
            "y": 23
        }
    ]
]
```

**[Photo1] Only for that specific bar "123" is correct.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you group the rects by color.
If you hover over a rect you get the datum that belongs to that color group. You have no indication of the bar you are hovering over.

Select the groups by class not by element type.

```
var groups = svg.selectAll(".rgroups")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class","rgroups")
                .attr("transform","translate("+ (padding.left) + "," + (h - padding.bottom) +")")
                .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                    return color_hash[dataset.indexOf(d)][1];
                })
                .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

You have to transform your dataset so you have an object/array that represent all the data of a particular bar. `d3.nest` might help.

Then construct a `g` per bar and add the rects to this `g`. Then in the tooltip you will get the datum that belongs to this bar.

Have a closer look at the style for `.d3-tip.n:after`. It has an error.

Comment: Thanks for your input! So far I've tried using `nested_data` variable, and implementing this like that: `var nested_data = d3.nest()
   .key(function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })
   .entries(dataset)`. And no luck yet.

Comment: Also, I have no idea how to construct a `g` per bar and add rects to that `g`, I'll try to figure that out too.

Comment: where in your original data do you have the field `y0`? The key field you need to use is the `time` field.

Comment: before `d3.nest` flatten your dataset first. If you also calculate the `stack(dataset)` you get nice objects you can use to construct a `rect` (`y0` is the cumulative sum of the previous rects in the list)

Comment: I'm not sure how can I flatten the dataset. Also, I can change the `return d.y0 + d.y` to `return dataset.time`, but it won't do anything because I need somehow to flatten the dataset according time and also sum the three of them.

Comment: Well, I almost made it. I'll update soon. It's showing the tooltip for every color that the mouse is hovered.

Comment: flatten an array means: loop over the first index, then loop over the second index and put all the elements in a new list, so all records with the `time` field get indexed with only 1 index.

Comment: I made it work eventually. and yes I did like you described. Thx RioV